# Error al crear un dato referenciado

Tags: sql, oracle, object

Estoy intentado hacer un ejercicio con objetos dentro de la base de datos y estoy algo atascado, los objetos y tablas las he creado de la siguiente forma:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
-- TAREA PROG10: CREACIÓN DE LOS TIPOS Y TABLAS
--------------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Type TIPO_MUEBLE
--------------------------------------------------------


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TIPO_MUEBLE AS OBJECT( 
    IDMUEBLE            NUMBER(4),
    DESCRIPMUEBLE       VARCHAR2(50),
    PRECIOUNITARIO      NUMBER(8,2),
    UNIDADESEXISTENTES  NUMBER(4)
)

/
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Type TIPO_VENTA
--------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TIPO_VENTA AS OBJECT(
    IDVENTA         NUMBER(6),
    NOMBRECLI       VARCHAR2(30),
    UNIDADESVEND    NUMBER(4),
    MUEBLE   REF TIPO_MUEBLE -- Mueble que se ha vendido    
)

/

--------------------------------------------------------
--   Tabla MUEBLES
--------------------------------------------------------
-- CREAR TABLA MUEBLES_OBJ
CREATE TABLE MUEBLES_OBJ OF TIPO_MUEBLE(
    IDMUEBLE PRIMARY KEY);

--------------------------------------------------------
--  Tabla VENTAS
--------------------------------------------------------
-- Crear tabla VENTAS_OBJ
CREATE TABLE VENTAS_OBJ OF TIPO_VENTA(
    IDVENTA PRIMARY KEY);
```

He insertando un objeto de tipo_muebles sin problemas mediante:

```
INSERT INTO MUEBLES_OBJ VALUES(0001, 'Mesa comedor', 15, 10);
```

Pero cuando quiero incluir un objeto de tipo_venta de la siguiente forma, de devuelve este error:

```
INSERT INTO VENTAS_OBJ VALUES(000001, Luis, 2, 0001);

--ERROR

Error que empieza en la línea: 51 del comando -
INSERT INTO VENTAS_OBJ VALUES(000001, Luis, 2, 0001)
Error en la línea de comandos : 51 Columna : 39
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Creo que el error lo tengo en el 0001 que tengo que poner un tipo_mueble, pero no se como hacer eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos si esto te vale. No he podido probarlo, así que ya nos contarás:

```
INSERT INTO VENTAS_OBJ
VALUES(000001, 'Luis', 2, (SELECT ref(mueble) FROM MUEBLES_OBJ mueble WHERE IDMUEBLE = 0001));
```

De todas formas, te comento que esta forma de gestionar los datos está muy desaconsejada. Es poco clara, y da muchos errores. Pero si te vale para el ejercicio, perfecto.

Vale, para futuras referencias, el problema era que habías puesto Luis en el campo de tipo VARCHAR, dejándote las comillas, así que el gestor estaba suponiendo que le estabas dando el nombre de una columna.

Comment: Justo ahora si funciona de maravilla, gracias

Answer (score 0):

he probado lo que me comentas, pero de arroja el siguiente error.

```
Error que empieza en la línea: 59 del comando -
INSERT INTO VENTAS_OBJ
VALUES(000001, Luis, 2, (SELECT ref(mueble) FROM MUEBLES_OBJ mueble WHERE IDMUEBLE = 0001))
Error en la línea de comandos : 60 Columna : 16
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Espera, me acabo de fijar en algo. Voy a modificar mi respuesta, prueba de nuevo, y responde editando la pregunta o añadiendo comentarios, ¿ok?